# What am I doing wrong with my caulk?

Tags: tile, bathtub, caulk

I pulled/scraped out the old caulk and grout from around this tub where it meets the walls/floor, and replaced it.  Just a couple weeks later, I see very large cracks in the caulk, and several places where it is just pulling away from the tub or wall entirely.

Previously there was grout behind much of the caulk, but I thought I learned that (rigid) grout was to be avoided on 90-degree joins (between wall and floor, etc).

I used a straight razor to remove old residue, and then isopropyl alcohol to clean the surfaces.
The caulk is [DAP Kwik Seal Plus,](https://www.dap.com/products-projects/product-categories/caulks-sealants/latex/kwik-seal-plus/) which says a 3/8 joint is Ok without backing... but maybeI need that anyway?

Thank you for any and all suggestions!

[image: vertical caulk joint with large cracks]
[image: caulked corner with large cracks]
[image: horizontal caulk joint with small cracks forming]

Comment: Do you still have the caulk tube? Can you decipher the manufacture date? (Reason I bring it up is that old caulk -- especially some of the hybrids like you have -- can go bad after a while.) And did you manage to clear all the old silicone? My test is to rub a dirty finger on it; if there's dirt sticking, you need more razor blade time.

Comment: Filling the tub with water before caulking will help also, but unsure about down the side of the tub.  On top yes.

Comment: It's certainly possible I missed some old residue, at least where it's pulled off the tile/tub completely.  When I redo this I'll be more aggressive cleaning.

@crip659 is the idea to load it up with weight so it displaces a little? Or is that about moisture/humidity?

Comment: It sinks the tub a bit, so when empty it stuffs/pushes the caulking up, instead of pulling the caulking apart when using the tub.  Should not matter down the side of the tub, so might be old caulking also.

Comment: Ah, that's even more clever! I thought it was just to mimic the position if it was in use... but having it "push up a little" on the finished caulk could help too.

I emptied the first tube, but the second one has "123221" as the date/batch code... which means little to me.  Another DAP tube I have says 121245 so I'm not sure what part of that could be year or month or week, alas.

Comment: Couldn’t find anything on dap.com regarding manufacture dates… maybe call or chat with them.

Comment: I'm not sanguine about using acrylic caulk in a wet location...